# Is it better to stand or sit for kegavna?

Tags: tefilla, standing-sitting, kabbalat-shabbat

*Kegavana* is an Aramaic paragraph that is commonly recited in Nusach Sefarad on Friday nights after *Kabbalat Shabbat* and before the beginning of *Ma'ariv* (*Barchu*).

Is it better for one to stand or to sit while saying it?

As it is a meditation relating to Barchu and to receiving the additional neshama, it might be better to stand. But as it may be considered learning Torah (according to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81818/rademishel-velomar-barchu/81935#81935)), perhaps one should sit. What are the prevalent minhagim?

Comment: Why should one sit for learning Torah? Originally you had to stand to learn Torah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23184/759

Comment: to stand up to barechu

Comment: Based on the analysis in your linked answer, *Bameh madlikin* said in Nusach Ashkenaz is a better candidate to be considered learning Torah. After all, that one is Mishnah, whereas *Kegavna* is Zohar (I think. I don't recall its source.) So, why aren't most people standing for *Bameh Madlikin*? I don't attend Nusach Sefard shtiebls that often. But, from what I have seen, they sit and rise for *Barchu*.

Comment: You have two questions, so I think you need to delete one. "What should one do" is very different from "what is the prevalent custom that people are doing".

Comment: "As it is a meditation relating to Barchu " - is it? From what I recall, *Kegavna* discusses the beauty of Shabbat and, I think, it has a reference to *Shema*. I don't think it's about *Barchu*.

Comment: Yes, the Zohar passage leads up to a reference to Barchu, but cuts off at that point and the actual Barchu is recited.

Comment: I've been to a bunch of Chassidishe shuls both in the greater NY area and in Israel. Everyone stands for Kegavna. Have you found a source to sit?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/95748